# Trigonometric ratios and identities

Tags: trigonometry

If the value of $\sin^26°+\sin^242°+\sin^266°+\sin^278°$ is expressed in the lowest form as $\frac{p}q$, then find the value of $(p+q-10)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Show what you have tried so far and use mathjax so that the people on this site can better understand your question.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show what you tried and where you are stuck. Please use mathjax for mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Have you tried finding the value of $\sin^2 6 + \sin ^2 42 + \sin ^2 66 + \sin ^2 78$?

Comment: **Hint:** $\frac pq = \frac 94$. Hope that solves your question.

Comment: i need the solution without using the values of the given trigonometric functions.

Comment: What do you mean?????????????????? Why were you given those trigonometric functions then?

Comment: Do you want an answer that shows some proving instead of directly inputting values into a calculator?

Comment: we are supposed to use identities and manipulations to solve. we aren't allowed to use calculators in examinations.

Comment: I would have preferred if you specified that in the question. Nevermind, working on the proof for you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$

to find the summands to be

$\cos12^\circ,\cos(12+72)^\circ,$

$\cos(12+2\cdot72)^\circ,$

$\cos(12+3\cdot72)^\circ=\cos(360-228)^\circ$

Now use [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro)

Comment: When you write up an answer only to find someone else correctly answered before you. It was my good fortune that I checked your answer else my answer would have been flagged as duplicate! Really a neat answer (took less space than mine). +1

Comment: thank you lab bhattacharjee ! your answer was indeed very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^26°+\sin^242°+\sin^266°+\sin^278°=$$
$$=\frac{1-\cos12^{\circ}+1-\cos84^{\circ}+1-\cos132^{\circ}+1-\cos156^{\circ}}{2}=$$
$$=2-\frac{1}{2}(\cos12^{\circ}+\cos132^{\circ})-\frac{1}{2}(\cos84^{\circ}+\cos156^{\circ})=$$
$$=2-\frac{1}{2}\cos72^{\circ}+\frac{1}{2}\cos36^{\circ}=2-\frac{2\sin36^{\circ}\cos72^{\circ}-2\sin36^{\circ}\cos36^{\circ}}{4\sin36^{\circ}}=$$
$$=2-\frac{\sin108^{\circ}-\sin36^{\circ}-\sin72^{\circ}}{4\sin36^{\circ}}=2+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{9}{4}.$$
Id est,
$$p+q-10=3.$$